# Where are certain drives in my Ubuntu box?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, raid

So I have a box with Ubuntu Desktop 16.04. The box has a 120 GB SSD as boot and two 4 TB HDDs set to RAID 1. I am more familiar with Windows file system, but wondering how I can tell where exactly two 4 TBs disks in terms of space are? Basically, I know I only get 4 TB of usable space, but I want certain info on that particular RAID array. Will listed in Linux as shown in screenshot, I am not sure where that space is whereas in Windows, I would see a separate drive altogether.

When I run sudo `fdisk -l`, I get:

[image]

When using gnome-disks, I see this:

[image]

Comment: Try `df` at the shell prompt.

Comment: (1) [Please don’t post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408).  (2) “/dev/sda: 3.7 TiB” and “/dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB”.  What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: This is set to Raid 1 as (2) 4 tb HDD's. So the usable space should only be 3.7tb total, no? Also,based on the images shown, do I need to format these or something and name them something in order to access them as something other than /dev/sda(b)? Make sense? In other words, if those 2 drives were to have just home media such as pics, movies, etc...., then I would expect a folder somewhere called "Media" or something. Just curious on how to go about this.Additionally, these were supposed to be set as hardware raid, hence why part of the confusion.

Comment: Just because it's hardware raid doesn't mean that the system cannot query the system and find the disks under the raid array. As mentioned try running `df` or `cat /etc/mtab`  to see what disks are actually mounted. I'd expect to see a raid array under something other than sda and sdb. Bear in mind though that most motherboard based raid is actually what is known as "fakeraid" and is not a genuine hardware raid.

Comment: You can try mounting one of the hard drives and see if the files appear. Also check if linux even supports the HW RAID you are using. If you are permanently going to keep the RAID in linux, i would just create a software RAID. Much faster than hardware.